# An independent sequence of square-integrable random variables with convergent sum of variances converges stochastically

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent and square-integrable random variables with $\operatorname{E}\left[X_i\right]=0$ and $$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Var}\left[X_i\right]<\infty$$
Let $$X^{(n)}:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;D^{(m,n)}:=X^{(n)}-X^{(m)}$$
I want to show that $\left(X^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a *stochastic Cauchy sequence*, i.e. $$\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\Pr\left[\left|D^{(m,n)}\right|>\varepsilon\right]=0\;\;\;\text{for all }\varepsilon>0\tag{0}$$

---

I've tried the following:

- Since $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is independent, the *Bienaymé equation* yields $$V_n:=\operatorname{Var}\left[X^{(n)}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}\left[X_i\right]$$
- Thus, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}V_n=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Var}\left[X_i\right]<\infty$$ implies $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}V_n<\infty\tag{1}$$
- Moreover, $$\operatorname{E}\left[X^{(n)}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{E}\left[X_i\right]=0\tag{2}$$
- $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply the uniform integrability of $\left(X^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

So, if I could show $(0)$ - which implies that $\left(X^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges stochastically - I could conclude that $\left(X^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in $L^2$. However, I wasn't able to find an easy proof for $(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\delta>0$. Since $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \text{var} \, (X_i)<\infty$,  we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\text{var} \, (D^{(m,n)}) = \sum_{i=m+1}^n \text{var}(X_i) \leq \delta$$

for all $n \geq m \geq N$. By Markov's inequality,

$$\mathbb{P}(|D^{(m,n)}| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \text{var} \, (D^{(m,n)}) = \frac{\delta}{\epsilon^2}.$$

Since $\delta>0$ is arbitrary, this finishes the proof.

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I just started wondering whether we can even show that $\left(X^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2$?! This would yield convergence in $L^2$.

Comment: @oxbadfood That's correct. Since $$\|X^{(n)}-X^{(m)}\|_{L^2}^2 = \text{var} \, (D^{(m,n)}),$$ my answer actually shows that $X^{(n)}$ is an $L^2$-Cauchy sequence.

Comment: This answer effectively shows $X^{(n)}$ is a Cauchy sequence in probability. This establishes that $X^{(n)}$ converges in probability (or stochastically) to a function $X$, which as @saz has pointed out, is $L^2$. See, for example, Achim Klenke's "Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course", Corollary 6.15.